# In a .NET Maui Blazor application, can you play a video (HTML5) by pointing the source attribute directly to the path of a video file on file system?

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

I have a .NET Maui Blazor application and want to play an mp4 video within a razor page of the application by pointing the source of the HTML5 video element directly to the path of the video file on the user's file system, but can't get it to work. Is this possible?

When I include the mp4 video file in the actual .NET Maui Blazor project (under wwwroot/videos) and then point the HTML5 video element to it then the video plays. But this is not my requirement. I want the user to select the video file (using FilePicker) and then play the video inside the .NET Maui Blazor application.

This works (where the testvideo.mp4 file is included in the project under wwwroot/videos):

```
<video controls="controls" width="800px" height="462px">
    <source src="videos/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This does not work:

```
<video controls="controls" width="800px" height="462px">
    <source src="C:\videos\testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This does not work either:

```
<video controls="controls" width="800px" height="462px">
    <source src="C:/videos/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I might be wrong here but from what I understand you want your Windows app to forward a URI to the blazor control that should be able to read it and play your video?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve and I managed to get it right in the end. It started in my Blazor control where the user picked a file from the file system and converted the file into a blob (byte[]). I then passed the C# blob and the Id of the video element into a javascript function that then created a Url . The Url was then assigned to the src property of the video element.

The one "little" piece that I missed was to convert the C# blob into a Javascript blob, e.g. new Blob([blob]), where blob is the C# blob passed into the Javascript function.

Comment: Might wanna add that as an answer for someone else looking for the same

Comment: Are you ok to use the browser pickup file, like when you want to upload the file? if yes I can guide you as it is so easy to do that.